# forEach - adding key/value to action.data in Redux - console.log works but Redux state not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, foreach

Inside an async Redux action I collect some data using graphQL and then I call another async action which loops in the object (using forEach) and adds some keys.

In `UserTopicActions.js`:

```js
export const sendGetUserTopicSuccess = data => ({
    type: action_types.SEND_GET_USER_TOPIC_SUCCESS,
    data
});
 ...

export function sendGetUserTopic(user_id, nextToken = null) {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(sendGetUserTopicBegin());
        ...
        try {
            const data = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(gqlUserTopic.getUserTopic, variables))
            data_uri = await getCarouselImgUri(data.data.getUserTopic)
            dispatch(sendGetUserTopicSuccess(data_uri));

        } catch (err) {
            dispatch(sendGetUserTopicFailure(err));
        }
    };
}
```

In `amplifyAsync.js`:

```js
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

export default async function getCarouselImgUri(raw_data) {
    data = JSON.parse(raw_data.data)
    topics = data.topics
    // Fetching thumbnails for cards
    let card_img_uri
    topics.forEach((topic) => {
        topic['subtopics'].forEach(async (subtopic) => {
            card_img_uri = 'topic/' + topic.id + '/' + subtopic.id + '/' + 'thumbnail.jpg'
            subtopic['uri'] = await Storage.get(card_img_uri)      <------------ New Key!
        })
    })
    console.log(topics)
    return topics

}
```

In `UserTopicReducer.js`

```js
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SEND_GET_USER_TOPIC_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                isGettingUserTopic: true,
            };
        case SEND_GET_USER_TOPIC_SUCCESS:
            console.log(action.data)
            return {
                ...state,
                isGettingUserTopic: false,
                topics: action.data
            };
    ...
```

If I console.log the action.data in the reducer, I see the new keys. On the other hand, in the *state and the dispatched `SEND_GET_USER_TOPIC_SUCCESS` action* the new keys are not present.

Why? How can add new keys in the data of an Redux async action?

Comment: After painful hours I found the mistake:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few painful hours I found the mistake:

In `amplifyAsync.js`:
`Async ... wait` does not assure that all the promises inside the `forEach()` are resolved.

I think the best solution would be to place all promises in an Array and then use promise.all, but since I wanted to keep the same dictionary structure (and promise.all does not work with dictionaries) I temporarily used a normal for look and async await. In this way all requests are done sequentially. It’s a non optimized solution but for now it works.

When debugging promises make sure you do`console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` otherwise a standard `console.log(data)` might print a value of the resolved promise that might not have been available at execution time.